# Do we lose most of our body heat through our heads?

Tags: medical-science, biology

[image]

If you didn't grow up in a tropical climate, you probably heard something like this as a child...

> Put on a hat before you go out because
>   you lose the most heat through your
>   head.

Some say that the reason you lose more heat through your head is because "heat rises" and most of your body heat naturally escapes though your head.

Is this true?

**Does more body heat escape from our heads than from other parts of the body?**

Comment: just thinking about the surface area of the body will dismiss the idea of "heat rising". The idea of heat rising only applies to gases and liquids NOT solids.

Comment: But surface area isn't everything. Blood circulation is also extremely important. Anecdotally: I spent quite a lot of time hiking in New Zealand. I found that the strongest impact on how warm or cold I felt was putting on or off a hat. I'm curious what the answers on this will be

Comment: "_No, mom,_ _[Science](http://jap.physiology.org/content/101/2/669.abstract?ijkey=e6f5a68ff9481c54444d0a5c9b1b17880313ba21&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha) says I don't need to wear a hat_ !"

Comment: @Oliver_C I wish I'd noticed your link earlier...would have saved me a bunch of time :)

Comment: We also had a saying for outdoorsmen - "if the feet are cold, put on a hat". I don't have empirical evidence for this - but plenty of happy hillwalkers and campers with anecdotes ;)

Comment: I was told the same thing but for a different reason. Not because "heat rises" but because our heads have much less insulation compared to the rest of our body parts. The same goes for our hands and our feet, along with the fact that these are extremities.

Comment: To add to the anecdotes, I was told flat-out to wear a stocking cap while cross-country skiing.  If I got warm, I was to turn up the cap to expose my ears, and if I was still warm to remove it altogether.  It seems to work effectively.

Comment: @Lagerbaer what things did you try that had less impact than the hat?  How thick is your hair?  Did the hat cover your ears?  Were you wearing gloves, or, more broadly, what other skin was exposed?  If your only exposed body part is your head then *of course* most lost heat will be lost through your head.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

<sub>**Apperently...**</sub>

> You can lose 40 to 45 percent of body
>   heat from an unprotected head and even
>   more from the unprotected neck, wrist,
>   and ankles. These areas of the body
>   are good radiators of heat and have
>   very little insulating fat. The brain
>   is very susceptible to cold and can
>   stand the least amount of cooling.
>   Because there is much blood
>   circulation in the head, most of which
>   is on the surface, you can lose heat
>   quickly if you do not cover your head.
>   -  [FM 21-76 US ARMY SURVIVAL MANUAL](http://www.ar15.com/content/manuals/FM21-76_SurvivalManual.pdf), BASIC PRINCIPLES OF COLD
>   WEATHER SURVIVAL, PG 148.

<sub>**Can this be right ? Does more body heat escape from our heads than from other parts of the body ?**</sub>

**Short Answer: No.**

> In general, heat loss is essential to
>   provide thermoregulation and prevent
>   excessive heat build-up in the body to
>   avoid the consequences of heat stroke.
>   However, heat loss in the head is the
>   same as for any exposed body part. The
>   exposed surface area of the body,
>   along with relative humidity and
>   temperature, determines heat loss
>   primarily through evaporation and our
>   head makes up only 10 percent of body
>   surface area.  So, **at rest**, heat
>   loss through the head accounts for
>   only 7-10 percent of total heat
>   dissipation. - [source](http://researchfrontiers.uark.edu/12401.php)

See below: General heat loss through the head.

---

## EXCEPT...

> As you **begin
>   exercise, cerebral blood flow
>   increases due to increased cardiac
>   output and the percentage of heat lost
>   through the head accounts for about 50
>   percent of total body heat loss.**  As
>   exercise continues, more oxygen is
>   directed toward muscle and blood flow
>   to this tissue increases. Core
>   temperature has to be maintained and
>   as body heat increases, the skin
>   arterioles expand, or vasodilate,
>   redirecting blood flow to the skin
>   which cools the blood. Hence, total
>   blood flow to the brain is decreased
>   and the percentage of total body heat
>   lost through the head is reduced to
>   about 10 percent. The percent lost
>   through the scalp returns to 7 percent
>   after sweating begins. - [source](http://researchfrontiers.uark.edu/12401.php)

**Shivering is exercise...**

> But, this is important, **if they are
>   shivering, the percent of heat loss
>   via the scalp can increase to upwards
>   of 55%**, so protecting the head well is
>   a very important part of treating the
>   hypothermia patient.  And as you can
>   imagine, the primary defense against
>   the cold and hypothermia is
>   vasoconstriction of the peripheral
>   circulation, this shunts blood to the
>   core, reduces circulation to the skin,
>   and **increases the percent of heat loss
>   through the scalp.** - [source](http://wildernessmedicinenewsletter.wordpress.com/2007/02/14/heat-loss-through-the-head-and-hypothermia/)

---

**General heat loss through the head**

> source: [Thermal effects of whole head submersion in cold water on
>   **nonshivering** humans](http://jap.physiology.org/content/101/2/669.full)
>
> One hypothesis predicts a substantial
>   heat loss through the head due to the
>   great amount of surface blood flow in
>   the scalp and because scalp blood
>   vessels do not vasoconstrict in
>   response to cold as do surface vessels
>   in other body areas (8). An
>   alternative hypothesis predicts
>   minimal heat loss from the head
>   because submersion of the head and
>   neck would only involve 7–9% more of
>   the body surface area (20). As well,
>   mathematical modeling predicts minimal
>   conductive heat loss directly through
>   the scalp and skull (27).
>
> The present results are consistent
>   with previous data (9) in that the
>   **supposition of proportionately greater
>   heat loss from the head was not
>   supported.**
>
> [image: Cutaneous Heat Loss]
>   <sub>*Whole body cutaneous heat loss
>   (n = 8) values for baseline (20 min)
>   and immersion (30 min) periods.*
>   **Greater than body-insulated conditions, P <
>   0.001. †Greater than head-out in the same subconditions, P < 0.05.*</sub>
>
> The measured heat loss from the head
>   in both head-in conditions was only
>   100 kJ (compared with 17 kJ in the two
>   head-out conditions). In contrast,
>   total heat loss in the body-exposed
>   configurations was 914 and 988 kJ, for
>   head-out and head-in conditions,
>   respectively. In the latter case, the
>   head accounted for only 10% of the
>   total body heat loss when both the
>   head and body were submersed. The
>   surface area of the submersed head is
>   7% of the total surface area of the
>   body.
>
> [image: Total Heat Loss]    <sub>*Energy
>   production and loss during 30 min. of
>   immersion in 17°C water (n = 8). Total
>   loss includes whole body cutaneous and
>   respiratory heat loss. Body loss
>   includes trunk, legs, and arms.*
>   **Greater than body-insulated conditions, P < 0.001. †Greater than
>   head out in the same subconditions, P
>   <
>   0.005. ‡Greater than head-out conditions, P < 0.001.*</sub>
>
> **These results thus indicate that heat loss from the head is not
>   disproportionately increased over what
>   would be expected from the head’s
>   contribution to total body surface
>   area.**

**However...**

> **With the body exposed to cold water
>   and shivering intact, additional
>   dorsal head immersion increased core
>   cooling from 3.8 to 9.4°C/h (250%) in
>   1–2°C water.**

---

## The Bottom Line...

**[Oliver_C](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/454/oliver-c) is correct: "No, mom, Science says I don't need to wear a hat !..."**

**"...Ok, mom, I'll bring one along just in case I get cold !"**

---

<sup>Cited and worth a read...

(8) Froese G and Burton AC. Heat loses from the human head. J Appl
Physiol 10: 235–241, 1957.

(9) Giesbrecht G, Lockhart T, Bristow G, and Steinman A. Thermal
effects of dorsal head immersion in cold water on nonshivering humans.
J Appl Physiol 99: 1958–1964 2005.

(20) Layton R, Mints WJ, Annis J, Rack M, and Webb P. Calorimetry with
heat flux transducers: comparison with a suit calorimeter. J Appl Physiol
54: 1361–1367, 1983.

(27) Xu X, Tikuisis P, and Giesbrecht G. A mathematical model for human
brain cooling during cold-water near-drowning. J Appl Physiol 86: 265–
272, 1999.</sup>

Comment: Holy oscillating font sizes, batman.

Comment: @DuckMaestro the unreadably small fonts cover the spelling errors.

Answer (score 27):

Bear in mind that *the rest of the body is usually clothed* which provides the most important insulation of the body, as can be seen in a thermal scan image:

[image: thermal imaging system screening passengers for H1N1 flu]

[Scale is heat loss from least (bottom, blue) to most (top, red/white); source: [Britannica.com](http://www.britannica.com/EBchecked/media/129991/A-quarantine-officer-at-Incheon-International-Airport-in-South-Korea)]

However, this image also shows that hair is actually a pretty good insulator as well. So while a clothed human indeed loses much of their heat through the head, donning a hat won’t help.

There is another aspect: the body will strive to keep the *core body temperature* constant. If necessary, it does this by [down-regulating blood circulation (and consequently heat exchange) in the periphery](http://openwaterchicago.com/2008/05/09/hypothermia-series-part-5-the-afterdrop-phenomenon/) (arms, legs); in contrast, the blood circulation through the head (in particular, the brain) stays almost constant:

[image: Body core temperature]

In fact, next to the trunk (clothed!) **the head emits the most amount of heat per area** (skin temperature of 34.6°C) [source: [Blatteis, *Physiology and pathophysiology of temperature regulation*, p. 17](http://books.google.com/books?id=if9jXQvVylgC&lpg=PP1&dq=Physiology%20%5Cpathophysiology%20temperature&pg=PA17#v=onepage&q&f=false)], **and also the most total energy of any non-clothed area** [ibd.].

So yes, when clothed (and not immersed in water; this diminishes the insulating effect of clothing significantly!) we do indeed lose most of our body heat through our head. However, except for bald people, hats may not help that much (to maintain the core body temperature).

Comment: Hmm I thought this had been debunked somewhere I'll have to have a hunt.

Comment: I think this is the paper (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1351377/), but i've not had a chance to read through it yet, I'll try and get the time tomorrow.

Comment: @Konrad "In fact, next to the trunk (clothed!) the head emits the most amount of heat per area"are you comparing a covered trunk to an uncovered head in this answer?

Comment: but donning a hat WILL help tremendously if it covers the ears.  love your use of the word 'don' btw

Comment: @Ardesco This concerns a single layer of clothing which is either wet or dry. This is a very specific and completely different situation from the ones mentioned by me (clothed, normal or immersed in water). Which part of my answer does this debunk?

Comment: @Monkey In the sentence you cite I am comparing unclothed body parts. But yes, my point is that the head has the greatest per area temperature loss once you exclude the clothed parts of the body (since multiple layers of clothing reduce heat loss drastically).

Comment: The amount of actual hair one (still) has might be a nice confounding factor. I've personally found that as my hairline receded, hats made a much larger difference in my personal comfort level in cold weather. They also prevent scalp sunburn in full sun, which those who still have full heads of hair don't have to worry about nearly as much.

Comment: @jon I wasn’t sure about this – it sounds plausible but I was unable to find data so I omitted a discussion of ears.

Comment: @Konrad, as I said in the comment I've not read through it yet :), i'm pretty sure there is evidence out there that debunks this as a 50 year old US military myth though.  Looks like Rusty has done a decent job at first glance.

Comment: @Ardesco Again: *what exactly* is to be debunked here? Also see my comment to Rusty’s answer.

Comment: @Ardesco My revised answer sheds more light on the Army claim.

Answer (score 2):

Reports say that the claim is a misunderstanding of the user manual for an early survival suit. If your body is well wrapped, then the head becomes the main vector of heat loss.

But not overwise.

http://www.guardian.co.uk/science/2008/dec/17/medicalresearch-humanbehaviour

Answer (score -1):

There are real life consequences to cold water immersion, such as in the sea. The head is the only part of the body exposed, so what happens is waves continually wet the head and then the wind evaporates the water thereby cooling the head far more effectively than if the head remained dry and free from wind. In this case the head does lose a lot more heat than other parts of the body which will typically have clothing on which acts in some way as an insulator. This is why some life jackets have built in wind proof hoods. Couple that with a thermal hat and the head is no longer a major heat loss.

Comment: Welcome to Skeptics. Please read the Help Center and see that all answers must be referenced.